# Regex match function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using a positive lookahead regex to get the matched string, but it gives me `Syntax error in regular expression` in IE8 what am I doing wrong. I want to match the very 1st occurrence.

Matching input

```
<IMG title="Configuration older than 90 days" alt=true src="http://indwdev:6130/include/images/expired.png"><IMG title="Converted configuration" alt=true src="http://indwdev:6130/include/images/convert.png">
```

My regex `str.match(/(?<=Converted configuration" alt=)[\w]+(?=)/)`

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pT4d4/2/).

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to [parse it instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @AlexWayne: how can this be parsed?

Comment: If the input is HTML, you can use jQuery to parse the HTML and search through the DOM as per normal. Regex is a sub par solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support positive lookbehinds in its regexes. You can use

```
str.match(/Converted configuration" alt=([\w]+)/)[1]
```

Comment: I want to fetch `true` in this case